# "+" and "-" output of the Jobs command

Tags: linux

What does the "+" and "-" signs mean in the following output of the jobs command.

```
-bash-4.1$ jobs
 [1]-  Running                 awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' final_ped.ped > only_ped &
 [2]+  Running                 awk '{if($6==1 || $6==2) print $1,$2}' final_ped.ped > comp_list &
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The character '+' identifies the job that would be used as default for the fg or bg utilities; this job can also be specified using the job_id %+ or "%%" . The character '-' identifies the job that would become the default if the current default job were to exit; this job can also be specified using the job_id %-.

From here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/output-of-jobs-command-563880/

Comment: Interesting.  Why isn't this info available via 'help jobs'?

Comment: I don't know.  It was oddly difficult to find....

Comment: `man jobs` was oddly unhelpful, and couldn't find anything using `info`.